# OpenSource Tool for Schema compare and upgrade Scripts

Tags: oracle, schema, compare

Are there any Open Source tools to compare different Oracle Schemas and provide the upgrade scripts.

ManyThanks,
Chandra

Comment: Do you really need an *open source* tool?  Or are you just looking for something you don't have to pay for?

Comment: I am looking for something I don't have to pay for...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any Open Source tool, but if you want a Free tool, you can use Oracle SQL Developer.

You have there a Database Compare tool and many other useful things.

You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html):

Comment: Careful here.  The Database Diff tool uses functionality from the Change Management Pack, and as such requires an additional license.  Although as I understand it this is nottruw with the very latest version ( 3.1 ) but I haven't seen a definitive statement on this.

Comment: I tried using the Oracle SQL developer, but it is saying even the identical tables of different schemas also are different, It is checking the system level constraints for different schemas and saying they are different, how to avoid this?